# How to customize % symbol in makeprg command

Tags: command-line, replace, makeprg

When I set makeprg using:

```
set makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -g\ %\ -o\ %
```

and then invoke :make Vim does not pass proper filenames, because this command is translated as:

```
gcc -Wall -g file.c -o file.c
```

and executed. The compiler is then complaining that input and output files are the same, which is in fact dangerous. My question is how to change the second % in makeprg to have it without .c extension. The command exectuted should be like this:

```
gcc -Wall -g file.c -o file
```

I don't know what to put instead the second %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using a non-properly configured version of gnumake (Solaris OS, or mingw distribution of gcc under windows), you don't need to modify `&makeprg`. Its default value is already perfect for GNU compilation tools.

All you need to do is to set `$CFLAGS` with `:let $CFLAGS="-g -Wall"`, and compile with `:make %<`.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify what is being expanded using so called filename modifiers. See the help at `:h filename-modifiers` ([link](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)).

In your case you can e.g. use `:set makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ -g\ %\ -o\ %<`

See also the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-16.1)

Comment: Thank you, this is a wonderful answer and it solves my problem PERFECTLY!